# Cannot start Yarn processes

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

My `start-yarn.sh` cannot start resourcemanager and nodemanager processes

I set these options in yarn-env.sh scripts as suggested earlier.

```
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS="--add-modules java.activation"
export YARN_NODEMANAGER_OPTS="--add-modules java.activation".
```

My yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

My mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

When I start the yarn process in hadoop 3.1.2 in Ubuntu I get below error

```
Starting resourcemanager
ERROR: Cannot set priority of resourcemanager process 3147
Starting nodemanagers
localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of nodemanager process 3271
```

Comment: Maybe try `sudo start-yarn.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue by using Java 8 instead of Java 11, as I was running Hadoop 3.1 but the Java 11 runtime [is only supported](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP/Hadoop+Java+Versions) by Hadoop 3.3 and above.

Comment: Please don't use link only answer. Please provide some example with context. In the future the link may not work, and your answer would be useless